# How to deal efficiently with "Address already in use"?

Tags: linux, python, socket

If I attempt to run my own Python program which listens on a particular port, I may get:

```
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

If the program didn't terminate gracefully.

While this may be resolved by writing the program differently, as a system administrator, what is the right way to deal with it -- if you simply have a badly written program?

There doesn't seem to be any process using the port, yet it is still reserved for this use. lsof and netstat doesn't give me anything I can kill, so what should I do to quickly be able to reuse the port without modifying the program in question?

Comment: https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/addrinuse.html

Comment: what does `lsof -i:8080` give? 8080-> port

Comment: Refer to [linux - Python \[Errno 98\] Address already in use - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465959/python-errno-98-address-already-in-use)